# Insert a content control with OOXML

Tags: ms-word, office-js, openxml

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20simple%20ways,provide%20essentially%20the%20same%20result.) recommend the following way to add a content control:

```xml
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" >
        <w:body>
          <w:p/>
          <w:sdt>
              <w:sdtPr>
                <w:alias w:val="MyContentControlTitle"/>
                <w:id w:val="1382295294"/>
                <w15:appearance w15:val="hidden"/>
                <w:showingPlcHdr/>
              </w:sdtPr>
              <w:sdtContent>
                <w:p>
                  <w:r>
                  <w:t>[This text is inside a content control that has its container hidden. You can bind to a content control to add or interact with content at a specified location in the document.]</w:t>
                </w:r>
                </w:p>
              </w:sdtContent>
            </w:sdt>
          </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
 </pkg:package>
```

But if one looks closely, the content control is added inside a **paragraph** (`<w:p>`):

```xml
<w:sdtContent>
  <w:p>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>[This text is inside a content control that has its container hidden. You can bind to a content control to add or interact with content at a specified location in the document.]</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
</w:sdtContent>
```

Is there a way I can prevent adding it inside the paragraph and make it inline? Just removing the `<w:p>` tag doesn't work somehow. Also, I am familiar with the Word API for adding content controls. My scenario is such that I have to produce and OOXML and then insert in into the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `<w:p>` and `</w:p>` from inside the `<w:sdtContent>` element, then you have to wrap the <w:sdt> element in a `<w:p>` element, like this, otherwise Word will not recognize the content:

```
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" >
        <w:body>
          <w:p/>
          <w:p>
            <w:sdt>
                <w:sdtPr>
                  <w:alias w:val="MyContentControlTitle"/>
                  <w:id w:val="1382295294"/>
                  <w15:appearance w15:val="hidden"/>
                  <w:showingPlcHdr/>
                </w:sdtPr>
                <w:sdtContent>
                  <w:r>
                    <w:t>[This text is inside a content control that has its container hidden. You can bind to a content control to add or interact with content at a specified location in the document.]</w:t>
                  </w:r>
                </w:sdtContent>
              </w:sdt>
            </w:p>
          </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
 </pkg:package>
```

Viewed in Word, in "your" encoding style, the paragraph mark appears inside the content control. With the above encoding, it appears outside the content control, and that means that it is possible to insert content between the end of the control and the end of paragraph.